# Make shell output prompt in color

Tags: bash, terminal

I made it so my terminal outputs the current directory as part of the command line prompt. However, I'd like this part of the output to be in color. I tried adding these lines to my .bash_profile:

```
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
export PS2="${CYAN}\u@\H:\w$ ${NC}| => "
```

However, no color is outputted. I heard these sorts of color commands only work using `echo -e` but is there a way to also add them to my prompt?

Comment: Did you try `source ~/.bash_profile` first?

Comment: yes I did, no luck

Comment: Try it like this. This is what I have in my bash profile `export PS2="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "` if you're going for something similar.

Comment: looks fancy. I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: I actually have that set as my `PS1` but if you want it as `PS2` that could work

Comment: Because `PS2` is the continuation as opposed to `PS1` which is the main prompt.

Comment: You can use `tput` to set colors (and more) with `CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)` and `NC=$(tput sgr0)`. See http://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/ for more.

Comment: I think you did add it in `.bash_profile` & sourced it too. but you have changed `PS2`, which is continuation prompt (used for multiline commands). try entering just `if<enter>` on prompt. you will see the secondary prompt.